# How does namespace link to folders?

Tags: php, phpstorm

(I did look into how namespaces work, but people explain it from a functional PoV and not physical)

I have a problem with Laravel but that's not the real problem:
in a **blog/app** folder I have the following code

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//...
?>
```

For example the third file referred to is in
**\blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth**

How the hell does it even figure out that part **blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src** ?

I have tried "right-click go to declaration" with PhpStorm and it linked me to the right file. How did it know?
Using WampServer I opened  *app* not *vendor*...

Note: the reason I'm asking this is because I get *Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found in[...]* when I try to open that file... (even though PhpStorm found it!)

Comment: Look at the PSR standards. They detail different versions of how these are mapped. The rest is just a question of how well the IDE is implemented.

Comment: In Laravel projects (and all modern projects these days) Composer does class autoloading. PSR-4 defines the way how most (if not all) of such modern code maps classes to physical files. The reason for "class ... not found" must be because you have tried to execute that file directly .. which bypasses whole framework bootstrap logic and composer autoloader in particular. Follow Alex Howansky's answer and links mentioned there.

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive way to manage this relationship between namespace and physical file, they are not technically related. However, in order to alleviate the issue you're noting, the [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standard was created, which defines guidelines to tie namespaces to file system files.

In this particular case, that PSR-4 mapping is maintained automatically by [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). The Illuminate package should have a `composer.json` that tells Composer where it can find files for the Illuminate namespace. When you run `composer install`, Composer scans through all the dependent `composer.json` files and builds `vendor/autoload.php` from all those dependencies. So all you have to do is include `vendor/autoload.php` and you magically get access to everything in your dependencies list.